# Logstash _grokparsefailure error windows

Tags: windows, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

Newbie Alert!

I am learning to use logstash on windows for demoing to the team.
Please see the following configurations and results:

1)

```
 file content : 123
```

config file:

```
input {
file {
    path => "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\Demo\WriteText.txt"
    start_position => "beginning"
    }
    }

filter {
grok {
match => { "@message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:data}"}
}
}
output {
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

My commandline shows the following output:

```
{
"path" => "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\Demo\WriteText.txt",
"@timestamp" => 2017-06-20T16:18:33.956Z,
"@version" => "1",
"host" => "ABC",
"message" => "123"
}
```

// no data field is displayed in the above output

2)
contents of input text:
 789

config2:

```
grok {
 match => { "@message" => "%{NUMBER:data}"}
 }
```

output in command line:

```
output
{
"path" => "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\Demo\WriteText.txt",
"@timestamp" => 2017-06-20T16:22:56.167Z,
"@version" => "1",
"host" => "ABC",
"message" => "789",
"tags" => [
[0] "_grokparsefailure"
]
}
```

I am getting parse error for simple number input. So I am wondering If the problem is with windows .txt file and encoding or something because grok is able to parse it as GREEDYDATA but not as NUMBER. and there are no field tags in both the outputs.
Please help me in identifying the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My grok filter is trying to parse @message field.But there is no such field.

match => [
      "message","%{GREEDYDATA:data}"]
did the trick.